# Custom metric in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm supposed to design a custom metric that out-performs L2 when applied on MNIST with different algos.

```
from sklearn import neighbors

import utils
import math


# Extraction du dataset
x_train, y_train = utils.get_train_data()
x_test,  y_test  = utils.get_test_data()

def EuclideanDistance(x, y):
    return math.sqrt((y[0] - x[0]) ** 2 + (y[1] - x[1]) ** 2)

test_range = 10
test_results = []  # tableau d'enregistrements {nn: [uniform, distance]}

for k in range(test_range):  # will test all 'k' values from 2 to 'test_range + 1'
    n_neighbors = k+2
    print("\nTesting  k =", n_neighbors)
    error_rate = []
    for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
        knn_clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors,
                                                 metric=EuclideanDistance,
                                                 weights=weights)
        knn_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
        predictions = knn_clf.predict(x_test)

        error_rate.append(utils.count_error_rate(predictions, y_test))

    test_results.append({n_neighbors: error_rate})

print("\nResults:", test_results)
```

Doing that, I get the following results:

```
Testing  k = 2
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %

Testing  k = 3
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %

Testing  k = 4
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %
Error rate =      91.58316633266533 %

...
```

Which is obviously wrong. Why do I get the same output for my custom metric applied to different contexts?

Comment: what is "import utils" you use? looks like it is something selfmade. Another point is that you didn't show your data. is there a possibility that all datapoints are just classified the same when you use k=2 k=3 and k=4?

Comment: @FlorianH `utils` is used to load the dataset which is just MNIST. When I use the built-in euclidian metric given by sklearn, I get different results which helped me conclude k=3 seemed to be the best in this situation. Then I wanted to understand better how to try out my own custom metric, so I started with a euclidian function, but it gives me the same result for every `k`. I thus concluded that I wasn't properly implementing the custom metric. My question really is: how do I implement my own custom metric with sklearn? I can't find the documentation related to that.

Comment: okay, if you use mnist which are pictures with 28x28 = 784 pixels where your EuclideanDistance function looks only at the first 2 of them x[0] and x[1]. So you miss x[2] to x[783] in your calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your `EuclideanDistance` function independent of the length of your input data (your function looked at only 2 components instead of the 784 dimensions in MNIST):

```
def EuclideanDistance(x, y):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise ValueError("x and y need to have the same length")
    return math.sqrt(sum([(y[i] - x[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(x))]))
```

***EDIT** to your comment about efficency

If you go to pythons lib folder (/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py) you can see yourself how the function is written.
However the comment inside the function states:

> For efficiency reasons, the euclidean distance between a pair of row
>   vector x and y is computed as::
>
> ```
> dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y))
> ```
>
> This formulation has two advantages over
>   other ways of computing distances.  First, it is computationally
>   efficient when dealing with sparse data.  Second, if one argument
>   varies but the other remains unchanged, then  `dot(x, x)` and/or
>   `dot(y, y)` can be pre-computed.
>
> However, this is not the most precise way of doing this computation,
>   and  the distance matrix returned by this function may not be exactly 
>   symmetric as required by, e.g., `scipy.spatial.distance` functions.

Comment: I tried your solution (and fixed your indentation): it has found one error rate for `k=2` so far, in approximately 20 minutes. How can `sklearn` have the same distance metric but with much faster results ? This is too slow. :(